# Dropwizard: Remove INFO level logs but keeping DEBUG level logs

Tags: java, dropwizard

Below is my logging setting in config.yaml file:

> # Logging settings.
>
> logging:
>
> ```
>  # The default level of all loggers. Can be OFF, FATAL, ERROR, WARN,INFO, DEBUG, TRACE, or ALL.         
>  level: INFO
>
>  # Logger-specific levels.   
>  loggers:
>
>     # Sets the level for 'com.example.app' to DEBUG.
>     com.my.app: DEBUG
> ```

Is it possible to remove INFO level logs but keeping DEBUG level logs in DropWizard? For example, I want to do this on com.my.app's logs. I tried to set its logging level to DEBUG, INFO, WARN, ERROR but couldn't achieve the goal.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think that would be possible.

The levels FATAL, ERROR, WARN, INFO, DEBUG, TRACE represent the log granularity. Setting log level to WARN would display all log which are of level >= WARN i.e. FATAL, ERROR and WARN.

Why do you require INFO logs to be disabled + DEBUG logs to be enabled?

Comment: Probably because he wants to only see DEBUG logs and not to have a ton of INFO to scroll through, probably during the development.